# Independent samples bootstrapped T-test

Tags: t-test, bootstrap

I have some question regarding bootstrapping in R. I wish to use independent samples bootstrapped T-test. I would like to know: 1 how  I can  calculate p and t values.2. for means and CI of each sample, should I report the bootstrapped mean and CI of each group? and not the ones obtained from t-test?

I used the following code with regard to t-test (t value and p value), So, I wonder if it is correct with regard to t and p values.

AVGMR=Names_first_last$`Avg_ Readars-Mendeley`

B      <- 1000

t.star = numeric(B)

t.vect <- vector(length=B)

p.vect <- vector(length=B)

for(i in 1:B){ boot.c <- sample(subset(AVGMR, Gender==1), replace=T)

boot.c <- sample(subset(AVGMR, Gender==2), replace=T)

ttest  <- t.test(boot.c, boot.p)

t.vect[i] <- ttest$statistic

p.vect[i] <- ttest$p.value

}

Please help.

Comment: On each sampling step just calculate differences of means. And than find percent of differences which are higher or equal that you have from non-permuted data. It will be Your p-value. For bootstraping you have no need to compute any other statistics

Comment: Read Tim Hesterberg's publications on the bootstrap t.  The test statistic is in the form of a t statistic.